# gulp-inject says it injected files but target file remains the same

Tags: gulp, asp.net-core-mvc, gulp-inject

I am trying to inject all js files in the weebroot folder (except the ones in lib), and after running the task it says all the files were injected. Nothing really appears to be happening though. This is my task:

```
gulp.task('index', function () {
  var target = gulp.src('Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml');
  var sources = gulp.src(["./wwwroot/**/*.js", "!./wwwroot/lib/**"], { read: false });

return target.pipe(inject(sources))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('/Views/Shared'));
});
```

The strangest thing is that it worked once. I asked a colleague for help, and when she stood behind me it appeared to work, but the problem was that it seemed to have worked a lot of times, because I suddenly had hundres of scripts injected, so I deleted them. The next time I ran the task, the _Layout.cshtml file remained unchanged. I have this in my html head:

```
 <!-- inject:js -->
<!-- endinject -->
```

I have seen other posts ([Gulp inject not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32768874/gulp-inject-not-working)) with this issue, but they say it was solved by piping the result to file, which I believe I am doing at the end of the task

**EDIT:** Figured out what was wrong. I was missing a "." before the path. It worked with "./Views/Shared..."